# jQuery, Select (any all *) element on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging, dom

I'm building a debugging tool for myself. What I want it to do is place a class on any element whenever it's clicked.

Something like this:

```
$('*').click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('debug')});
```

That actually worked, except that it toggles "debug" for ALL elements.

For example:

```
<body>
<div id='3'>
    <div id='2'>
        <div id='1'></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

If I clicked on `<div id="1">`, it will add a class called "debug" to `<div id="2">` and `<div id="3">`.

What's happening is when you click on `<div id="1>`, it counts as a click to all 3, because technically, all divs were clicked. So I've thought about having an array that holds all the HTML elements.

So far, I have:

```
window.v = [];
$('*').click(function(){window.v.push(this)});
```

Following that, it's:

```
$(window.v[0]).toggleClass('debug');
```

Unfortunately, when this:

```
$(window.v[window.v.length]).toggleClass('debug');
```

...or the above executes, it doesn't do anything. Sometimes, it places the "debug" class on the body tag.

So, I'm not exactly sure if using an Array is the best route for this.  Does anyone else have any ideas on how to universally click on any element and place the debug class on it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this:

```
$( window ).click(function ( e ) {
    $( e.target ).toggleClass( 'debug' );
});
```

Binding click handlers to *all* DOM elements is a bad idea. Instead, bind one single click handler to the `window` object. You can do this because click events bubble up (the DOM tree). In order to determine which element was clicked, use `e.target`.

Simple as that `:)`

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ucpzq/1/

Comment: Sorry, ignore - I missed something.

Comment: I like this idea in general, but will it work if the click is handled at the object itself (like a button) and bubbling potentiallly blocked.

Comment: @jfriend No. If `event.stopPropagation()` is invoked in a click handler, the click event won't reach the `window` object.

Answer (score 1):

Cancel the bubble:

```
$('*').click(function(evt) {
    $(this).toggleClass('debug');
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```